Peek java nio.CharBuffer?
Is it possible to peek the next nio.CharBuffer character without taking it out of the buffer like get() would?
For blocking io, it seems PushbackReader` would suit, but I'm interested specifically in non-blocking.
Maybe there's another built-in class with functionality similar to CharBuffer + the ability to peek, or a way to implement peeking on top of CharBuffer?

Some confusion here: nothing gets "taken out" with get and I'm not sure how this connects in any way with blocking/non-blocking. What is your actual goal?

you posted the link to the documentation... search for methods like position(), mark(), reset() or, maybe better, get(int) combined with position()

All the XXXBuffer classes have relative get/put methods and absolute get/put methods. The relative methods get/put the data starting at the current position and advance the position (nothing is actually removed when getting). The absolute methods get/put the data starting at a given index and do not advance the position.

Also see the mark and reset methods.

public char peek(CharBuffer cb) {char result = cb.get();cb.position(cb.position()-1);return result;} is a simple implementation, but that assumes this is a correct and necessary step to your goal (which you didn't state)

@g00se Would return cb.get(cb.position()) be simpler and obtain the same?

The point is that the position should not be advanced

@g00se Correct. As Slaw already said, The absolute (get/put) methods get/put the data starting at a given index and do not advance the position. So my suggestion fulfils that. I have tried it.

Oh yes I see what you mean. Sorry you're right

Online demonstration: https://rextester.com/KPB66032

The answer to this question seems to be in the comments, and I’m a bit surprised that no one has wanted to post it an answer yet? @wusspuss, maybe you want to do it yourself if you agree that your question has been answered?
